# Could not load file or assembly while configuring Build vNext Agent

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, ctp, tfs-2015

When trying to configure a Build vNext agent I keep running into the following exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'VsoAgent, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
```

I already tried disabling strong name verification using "sn -Vr *,*" as sugested here: http://nakedalm.com/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-while-configuring-build-vnext-agent/

But that does not solve the error. I tried the same on VM's with Visual Studio 2013, 2015 CTP5 & 2015 CTP6.

I followed [this guide](http://vsalmdocs.azurewebsites.net/tfs/build/vs/deploy-agent) to configure the Build.vNext agent

EDIT: Some more info.

I'm trying to configure this on a VM in Azure. I've tried the default Visual Studio Templates from the Gallery. Which means VM's with Server 2012 R2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the latest version of the VSoAgent.zip file the problem went away.  It seems to have been fixed in a newer release of the Agent.

Answer (score 1):

Did you "unlock" the .zip file before unpacking it?

On some OS's, specifically Windows 10, I had to right click on the downloaded zip and click "unlock" before unpacking.

If you then run the .\ConfigureAgent.ps1 it should work.

Comment: To confirm, you ran the "strong name disable" command for both 32 and 64-bit frameworks?

Comment: Yes. I ran it for both the 32 bit and the 64 version.

Comment: Yes, this issue is the strong name 32 & 64 cmd.  In RTM/release, won't be required but this is the issue here